# Return all localStorage in 1 Object?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

How would it be possible to return an object containing all localStorage keys/values? Mainly to future-proof code as best as possible, rather than declaring known keys to store, I'm looking for a way to get everything.

For context: This will be used in a Chrome extension to synchronize preferences.

Comment: What's wrong with declaring known keys?

Comment: Why do you think this will "future proof" your data?

Comment: It's not future proofing the data, it's future proofing the synchronization mechanism. By synching all localStorage, any keys I decide to add in the future will not need to be added; they'll just automatically be included. Of course, the benefit here is that I can add new features that use different keys without worrying about whether or not that information will make it to their other browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to do that, you could simply loop through each item, and append the current item, separated by a space.

```
var allkeys = ""; ;
for (i=0;i < localStorage.length;i++) {
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    allkeys += key + " " + localStorage.getItem(key) + " ";
}
```

I put a space between each key and value so that you can use a Tokenizer or something similar to break apart using spaces as delimiters.  You could add in a "Key"+i and/or "value"+i descriptor  in front of each item to aid in parsing or looking for an item without having to loop through keys to find the matching one.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that? Besides, `localStorage` *is* an object, which contains all key:value pairs stored by the browser. If you want to copy it, you should loop through its properties.

What it looks like you want/need, though, is a wrapper that will abstract away the `localStorage` insterface, so you if you would change the way you store your data later, you would only need to change this wrapper without your code noticing any difference. I do that myself.

There are several libraries which achieve this with varying levels of complexity and/or functionality. For example, [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) lets you use `userData` in IE if `localStorage` isn't available. My own [Storage.js](https://github.com/passcod/Storage.js) only wraps `localStorage` but has methods to act on multiple items at once.

Comment: As mentioned, this is for a Chrome extension, where localStorage availability is guaranteed. However, your mention that localStorage _is_ an object is brilliant ;) Didn't think of that! Thanks :)